# Heroku 'sh: 1: next: not found'

Tags: heroku, deployment, next.js, tailwind-css

Please help, I am having this issue while deploying my nextjs app in Heroku, the app runs fine locally.

Below is the log from Heroku and my package.json file.

**Log:**

```
2021-08-13T07:26:20.752659+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-13T07:26:20.752685+00:00 app[web.1]: > @ start /app
2021-08-13T07:26:20.752688+00:00 app[web.1]: > next start -p $PORT
2021-08-13T07:26:20.752689+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-13T07:26:20.763505+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: next: not found
2021-08-13T07:26:20.769117+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-08-13T07:26:20.769496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-08-13T07:26:20.769568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-08-13T07:26:20.769636+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-08-13T07:26:20.772506+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! @ start: `next start -p $PORT`
2021-08-13T07:26:20.772533+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.3",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using a specific version of `next` in `package.json`, e.g., `"next": "^11.1.0"`.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, my app is now deployed on heroku

Answer (score 5):

this is because your app in Heroku does not have the "next npm"

To fix:

- visit your project dir
- open terminal
- hit the command `npm install next`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it install the npm dependencies.